# how to swap two tables in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to maintain two tables in dynamodb. one is primary table and another secondary table.
Primary table will have the recent data. Secondary table will store the previous version of data.
 I want to swap between primary and secondary table, so that  the API layer accesses the recent data . how to do this in AWS dynamodb?

Comment: Why don't you simply build this switch into the application?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using streams. Write and read in the primary table, and using dynamodb streams you can have a lambda duplicate the old data to a second table whenever there is a write event on the primary table.

This article goes into some detail about the process: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html